# How to download a pdf with python or curl?

Tags: python, curl, request

I want to download a PDF file using Python. I am aware that there are several SO Q&A about this issue. However, I was only able to find cases where the `URL` follows this format `http://www.example.com/example.pdf`.

The `URL` I use to download the file is the following: `http://dof.gob.mx/nota_to_pdf.php?fecha=25/07/2018&edicion=MAT`. If I open a browser and paste the `URL` in the search bar, I am taken to a blank page where I am prompted to save the file.

When I try to use the methods shown in several tutorial sites, or try to follow the advise I find in other SO questions, I am only able to download the HTML, the same thing happens when I try to do it using `curl` in the terminal.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You can use `urrlib`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/3275464

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow!

If you want to use **Python** use the `requests` [library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to get the initial page to check out the content (you will need to install it first via `pip` or `pipenv`):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://dof.gob.mx/nota_to_pdf.php?fecha=25/07/2018&edicion=MAT')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
>>> r.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> r.text
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n<html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content- 
Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\r\n<title>Diario Oficial de la 
Federación</title>\r\n</head>\r\n\r\n<body>\r\n<script>\r\n  
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function() . 
{\r\n  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new
Date();a=s.createElement(o),\r\n  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)\r\n  })
(window,document,\'script\',\'//www.google-
analytics.com/analytics.js\',\'ga\');\r\n\r\n  ga(\'create\', \'UA-32467343-1\', \'auto\');\r\n
ga(\'send\', \'pageview\');\r\n\r\n</script>\r\n</body>\r\n</html><script> 
self.location=(\'abrirPDF.php?archivo=25072018-MAT.pdf&anio=2018&repo=\'); 
</script><html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
charset=iso-8859-1">\n\t<script>\n\tfunction BorrarPDF()
\n\t{\n\t\tdocument.getElementById(\'cerrar\').src=\'cerrar_doc_imagen.php
archivo=\'+document.getElementById(\'pdf\').value;\n\t}\n\t
</script>\n</head>\n<body onUnload="BorrarPDF()">\n\n
<input type="hidden" value="25072018-MAT.pdf" id="pdf" name="pdf">\n\n
<iframe id="cerrar" width="1px" height="1px" scrolling="no" 
frameborder="0" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px">
</iframe>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

If you dig through that HTML, you will see that the page uses `self.location` to redirect to the PDF file when the page loads.

The *actual* URL for the PDF is:

```
http://dof.gob.mx/abrirPDF.php?archivo=25072018-MAT.pdf&anio=2018&repo=
```

So, if you do the same process again with the `requests` library, this time specifying the actual PDF file:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://dof.gob.mx/abrirPDF.php?archivo=25072018-MAT.pdf&anio=2018&repo=')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/pdf'
```

Now you have the PDF in the body of the request.

You can do the same with `cURL` -- you just need to ensure that you are grabbing the right thing (which admittedly is obfuscated by the webpage javascript function, probably by design).

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll definetly keep that in mind next time I try to download somehting. It was easier (for me) to download the file using `cUrl` after your observation, now I'm going to try and do it with python.

Answer (score 1):

A function doing the job with a progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

def download_file( url, filename):
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    with open(filename, "wb") as handle:
        for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
            handle.write(data)
```

Comment: It still just downloads the HTML file  instead of the PDF. I am looking into the urrlib, as you sugested in the comments.

Comment: tqdm is a very useful module. Thanks for the advice.